# FFplay: WASAPI can't initialize audio client (FFmpeg 3.4 binaries)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to playback a stream that is multicasted over RTP using ffplay on Windows 7 64 bits.
The computer that serves the audio over RTP runs:

```
ffmpeg -re -f dshow -audio_buffer_size 15 -ac 1 -i audio="Mic in at front Mic-in (Realtek" -ar 8k -acodec pcm_alaw -vn -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

The client runs:

```
ffplay rtp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

While this was working correctly in release 3.3, release 3.4 fails with this error:

```
SDL_OpenAudio (1 channels, 8000 Hz): WASAPI can't initialize audio client: CoInitialize has not been called.

No more combinations to try, audio open failed
Failed to open file 'rtp://127.0.0.1:5000' or configure filtergraph
```

Anyone has an idea of whats going on ?

Thanks

**UPDATE #1:**

A workaround is to specify an alternate output driver.
Set SDL_AUDIODRIVER environment variable value to the driver you want to use.
Under windows 7, *directsound* and *winmm* both solved my issue.

Comment: It seems to be an [SDL related Windows specific bug in FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6721).

Answer (score 8):

To solve the problem, it is better to set the `SDL_AUDIODRIVER` in user environment variables:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open Run. Type `SystemPropertiesAdvanced` and press OK button.
2. Press the `Environment Variables...` button.

[image: System Properties]

3. In User variables section, press the `New...` button.
4. In front of "Variable name" type `SDL_AUDIODRIVER`. In front of "Variable value" type `directsound` or `winmm`.

[image: New Variable]

6. Press OK buttons recursively.
7. Reopen the terminal and run ffplay.

Comment: Dont forget to restart the system after changing the variable.

Comment: It works, but I'm curious of the reason, and where does the solution come from... @Summit: "*Dont forget to restart the system after changing the variable*", no need, restarting the application is enough.